# jQuery ajax fails over https on same domain

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, https, get

I have switched my site over to requiring https, and have confirmed that all resources are being loaded from https (no non-secure content), however many of my ajax calls to local php scripts are now failing with no error (other than "(failed)").

E.g.

```
$.ajax({    type: "GET",
        url: '/dashboard/helper/total-promoshares.php?param=params...',
        success: function(data) {
        etc...
```

This works fine over http, and I can access the url in a browser using both http and https, however I am getting the following when the above is called from an https page:

```
GET https://myurl.com/dashboard/helper/total-promoshares.php?e=1234&service=facebook&_=1234
send foundation.min.js:20
v.extend.ajax foundation.min.js:20
e index.min.js:11
d
GET https://myurl.com/dashboard/helper/total-promoshares.php?e=1234&service=twitter&_=1234  send foundation.min.js:20
v.extend.ajax foundation.min.js:20
e index.min.js:11
d
GET https://myurl.com/dashboard/helper/total-promoshares.php?e=1234&service=linkedin&_=1234  
send foundation.min.js:20
v.extend.ajax foundation.min.js:20
e index.min.js:11
d
```

And in the request/response from the network tab:

```
total-promoshares.php?e=1234&service=facebook&_=1234    
GET
(failed)
foundation.min.js:20    
13 B    
531 ms
```

`curl 'https://myurl.com/dashboard/helper/total-promoshares.php?e=1234&service=facebook&_=1234' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: https://myurl.com/dashboard/analyze/' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36' --compressed`

`This request has no response data available.`

Please help!

Comment: What was the response code on the request?

Comment: What is response Status (200,301, 302 ) or  some thing else ?